# added theme doesn't work

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm creating theme to be added to my store but it doesn't work
here is default.xml in the following directory:
magento_directory\app\design\frontend\vendor_name\theme_name\layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customtext" template="MyTheme::customtext.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

here is my customtext.phtml file in the following directory
magento_directory\app\design\frontend\vendor_name\theme_name\templates

```
<div class="block" style="float: right;margin-bottom: 0.5%;margin-top: 0.5%;">
   <?php echo __('This is Custom Text'); ?>
</div>
```

and theme.xml file in the following directory
magento_directory\app\design\frontend\vendor_name\theme_name

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->

</theme>
```

Comment: Did you run the `php bin/magento s:up` command? after setting up the theme?
Also can you please upload a screenshot of the tree structure of your newly created theme?

Comment: And make sure you have created a `registration.php` file for your newly created theme

Comment: here is screenshot: https://i.postimg.cc/qqw3Pjjv/tree-structure.png
and yes I've run upgrade command and added resgistration.php file

Comment: You need to comply with the directory structure as follow: [https://i.postimg.cc/nLd7SdSV/Screenshot-from-2018-11-12-13-40-16.png]

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/YqsCP5Ms/tree-structure2.png

Comment: default.xml file path should be "Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml"

Comment: I know but according to this link https://www.icecubedigital.com/blog/magento-2-theme-development-customization-step-by-step-guide/
I need to put the textin the  theme next to search box so I created search folder

Comment: So, default.xml file path should be "Magento_Search/layout/default.xml"

Comment: In short, folder name Bit68/MyTheme/Search should be replaced by  "Bit68/MyTheme/Magento_Search"

Comment: is Magento here 'Magento_Search' for vendor name?

Comment: this will be your folder name, whom layout  / template you want to cutomize.

Comment: @NaveedAsim I know but when I enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront I found that folder name was 'Search' not 'Magento_search'

Comment: @YomnaMansour you might be seeing Block class name as classes naming translated without "module"

Answer (score 1):

you have incorrect folder structure, if you want to change template / layout of "**module-search**" module Then you should name that folder like that **Magento_Search**.

so like that, if you want to customize any template / layout of "**module-catalog**" your folder name will be "**Magento_Catalog**". in other words change "**module**" to "**Magento**" and then module name.

so here you will see **module** is replaced with **Magento** and module name will be named with first letter capital i.e search will become Search.